# wso2 api manager configuring the STORE and PUBLISHER security

Tags: api, wso2

I am running API Manager version 1.3.0 and have successfully connected the management console to our Active Directory domain.  I can login to the management console with no problems but I can't login to the Publisher or the Store.

The documentation sounded as though once the configureation of user-mgt.xml was complete it should work.  What am I missing?  Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What's the error message shown in UI and printed in the terminal,when trying to log in to Store/Publisher? Did you added necassary permissions for the role of the trying user as described in http://dist2.wso2.org/products/api-manager/1.3.0/APIManager-GettingStarted-v1.3.0.pdf

Thanks;

Comment: I get the following error errorMsgs.login For input string: "9445${carbon.context}"  I have added myself to all the roles in the admin console.   I couldn't explore the link because we block google docs.

Comment: In addition to the screen error above, the carbon.loc has the following error      Error occurred while checking for multiple user stores {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject}  I am not using multiple stores only 1 Active Directory